# Update/edit Rows in Database via PHP

Tags: php, sql, database

I am trying to make a script so selected rows in my database can be editted.

Though I am having no Luck.

Can some explain where Ive gone wrong please?

DATABASE INFO:

id

Name

Type

MadeBy

Submitted

text

date

key 1

key 2

key 3

key 4

key5

Checked

created on

The only fields I want to really allow people to edit is the Name and Text

so on my edit_guides.php

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$guides = mysql_escape_string(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guides WHERE id = '$id'"));
```

Im a little unsure on this one being correct?

Do I not need View or anything???

Then for the form:

```
    ECHO <<<END
<center>
    <FORM ACTION="edit_guide.pro.phpid=$id" enctype="multipart/form-data" METHOD=POST>
    <table width="446" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><center>Edit a Guide</center></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="79">Made By:</td>
        <td width="367"><input type="text" name="madeby" value="$guides[username]"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name of Guide:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value="$guides[name]"></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Filed Under:</td>
        <td><select name=filedunder>
                   <option value=guides>Guides
            <option value=dailies>Dailies Guides


           <option value=gg#h>Game Guides # - H


            <option value=ggiq>Game Guides I - Q


            <option value=ggrz>Game Guides R - Z


            <option value=helpfulguides>Helpful Guides


            <option value=newbie>Newbie Guides
    </select></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td valign="top">Content:</td>
        <td><textarea  name="coding" cols="50" rows="35" value="">$guides[coding]</textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Key Word 1</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="key1" value="None"></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Key Word 2</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="key2" value="None"></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Key Word 3</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="key3" value="None"></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Key Word 4</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="key4" value="None"></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Key Word 5</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="key5" value="None"></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><center><font size="-1"><i>
          <input type=submit name=Submit value="Edit">
        </i></font></center></td>
      </tr>
    </table></FORM>
```

However this shows on the page:

Made By: R

Name of Guide:  R

Filed Under:    Default (guides)

Content:    R

Then my edit_guides.pro.php
Though Im still unsure if this page works, As Im just not getting that far yet.

```
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $madeby = $_POST['madeby'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $coding = $_POST['coding'];
    $key1 = $_POST['key1'];
    $key2 = $_POST['key2'];
    $key3 = $_POST['key3'];
    $key4 = $_POST['key4'];
    $key5 = $_POST['key5'];
    $filedunder = 'guides';
    $filedunder2 = $_POST['filedunder'];




    if ((!$madeby) OR (!$name) OR (!$coding) OR (!$filedunder2) OR (!$key1) OR (!$key2) OR (!$key3) OR (!$key4) OR (!$key5))

    {

                   die(header("Location: $baseurl/staff/edit_guides.php?id=$id&error=Please+do+not+leave+any+info+blank."));

    }

    else

    {

mysql_query("UPDATE guides SET name = '$name' WHERE id = '$id'");
mysql_query("UPDATE guides SET fileunder = '$filedunder2' WHERE id = '$id'");
mysql_query("UPDATE guides SET coding = '$coding' WHERE id = '$id'");
mysql_query("UPDATE guides SET key1 = '$key1' WHERE id = '$id'");
mysql_query("UPDATE guides SET key2 = '$key2' WHERE id = '$id'");
mysql_query("UPDATE guides SET key3 = '$key3' WHERE id = '$id'");
mysql_query("UPDATE guides SET key4 = '$key4' WHERE id = '$id'");
mysql_query("UPDATE guides SET key5 = '$key5' WHERE id = '$id'");
        header("Location: $baseurl/staff/index1.php?error=The+news+has+been+updated+:)");
```

The main Issue Im having right now, Is its not showing the content (text) or anything from database only the letter R which means nothing to me.

Comment: How do I secure from that? Im new to php

Comment: about your code, you should read the PHP manual & example to learn more http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-query.php. You can't use the result of `mysql_query` the way you are doing, you have to use something like `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Comment: Now im really confused :( I look into that link

Comment: you could read this http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html to learn more about SQL injection and why this is dangerous. Also check that http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php to learn how to prevent SQL injections. You should learn SQL too (you can update multiple fields with one query), there are a tons of good tutorial about PHP & SQL on the web

Comment: I will look into those links. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Performing a select from a mysql database

```
mysql_connect(...);
mysql_select_db($schemaName);
$result = mysql_query($sqlQuery);
$record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
mysql_free_result($record)
```

and you'll have your record at $record (assuming your $sqlQuery returns a single record).

About the set of SQL queries at the end of your post, you should be aware that updating seven times the 'header' field will result just in storing $key5 variable value into header field in guides table, while other previous values are discarded.

Actually I don't understand the purpose of the last PHP script.

Comment: Sorry, can you give me an example of what you mean by record at $record (assuming your $sqlQuery returns a single record).

Comment: I meant that if your query is something like "select * from table where id = $id" you'll get a single record (assuming id is the primary key for the table). If your query should return several records (or none) you should use a while ($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) {} instead

Answer (score 0):

In your first code snippet you're escaping a result of the query instead of the query itself. Then you're trying to access the result without reading it first with `mysql_fetch_assoc` or similar function. At the end you have a gaping SQL injection vulnerability plus 8 separate queries when one would suffice. There are thousands of PHP+MySQL tutorials floating around the net, consider reading a few first.